# Oracle SQL Choosing between multiple rows with same date

Tags: sql, oracle

Basically what I am trying to do is assign an owner depend on their availability on a certain date. Now I have gotten it to assign correctly however once an owner is assigned I don't want it to look for the other ones since it is already assigned. The Pseudo code would be like this

```
if person1 is available today then assign person1
else if person1 is NOT available today then assign person2
else if person 2 is NOT available today then assign person3
else assign it to N/A
```

It's just matching both tables and seeing if the person is available today in order to match a person with an task
However like I mentioned before it does 3 rows for every task, this is how the results look like

State = 1 is available state = 2 is not available

```
+----------------+----------+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| ASSIGNED_OWNER | THE_DATE | STATE | TASKID | OWNER1 | OWNER2 | OWNER3 |
+----------------+----------+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| john           | 3/2/2018 |     2 |   1234 | john   | bob    | rick   |
| N/A            | 3/2/2018 |     2 |   1234 | john   | bob    | rick   |
| bob            | 3/2/2018 |     1 |   1234 | john   | bob    | rick   |
+----------------+----------+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

This is how it SHOULD look like once it assigns an owner then just dont do other entries for that taskid

```
+----------------+----------+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| ASSIGNED_OWNER | THE_DATE | STATE | TASKID | OWNER1 | OWNER2 | OWNER3 |
+----------------+----------+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| bob            | 3/2/2018 |     1 |   1234 | john   | bob    | rick   |
+----------------+----------+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Instead of outputing the 3 columns it should just check. Is John available this day? no, okay so is bob available today? Yes? Okay assign him. Don't even check owner3 anymore it's already assigned

I've tried tackling this, but I am not sure what is it that I am doing wrong. I read online that it was doing a cortesian product so it was just multiplying both tables together. Is this even possible with just PL/SQL or am I going to have to implement some other language here?

Thanks in advance for the help everyone hopefully I made myself clear

Here is how the two tables I'm calling look like
This one is ownerdata

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| TASKID | OWNER1 | OWNER2 | OWNER3 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|  12345 | john   | bob    | rick   |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

This one is calendar

```
+----------+-------------+----------+
| PERSONID | AVAIL_STATE | THE_DATE |
+----------+-------------+----------+
| john     |     2       | 3/2/2018 |
| bob      |     1       | 3/2/2018 |
| rick     |     1       | 3/2/2018 |
+----------+-------------+----------+
```

Comment: Where does the "date" come from? Is it an input variable to the query (for example, a bind variable)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do this. Note that I created the test data in a `WITH` clause (which is not needed in your real-life query since you have the base tables). In the `WITH` clause I also included the input date. In real life the input date may be a bind variable - you will have to adapt the query that way (then you won't need a `WITH` clause at all, perhaps).

Here is the strategy. I am referencing the different subqueries in the solution - see the aliases given in the code. In subquery `U` (for "unpivoted") I unpivot the first table, since it is better if there are multiple rows for the same task, one potential owner per row, with the "preference" encoded in a numeric column. The subquery `C` (for "calendar") extracts the owners who are available on the given date. Then we do an inner join of `U` and `C` on "owner" - that way we keep just the available owners on the given date, and we have the preference order. The result of this join may be empty if no owner is available on this date.

In the outer-most layer we do a left join of your `OWNERDATA` table with the result of this join, on `TASKID`. We select the owner with the lowest priority code (1, 2 or 3) using the `FIRST` aggregate function (many developers for some reason don't use it, but it is exactly the right tool for this job), and we use `NVL` to set the `ASSIGNED_OWNER` to `'N/A'` when no owner is available on that date.

```
with ownerdata ( TASKID, OWNER1, OWNER2, OWNER3 ) as (
    select 12345, 'john', 'bob', 'rick' from dual
  ),
  calendar ( PERSONID, aVAIL_STATE, THE_DATE ) as (
    select 'john', 2, to_date('3/2/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
    select 'bob' , 1, to_date('3/2/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
    select 'rick', 1, to_date('3/2/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual
  ),
  input_date ( dt ) as (
    select to_date('3/2/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual
  )
select   nvl( min(j.owner) keep (dense_rank first order by pref), 'N/A') as assigned_owner,
         (select dt from input_date) as the_date,
         o.taskid, o.owner1, o.owner2, o.owner3
from     ownerdata o
         left outer join
         (
           select taskid, owner, pref
           from     (
                      select  taskid, owner, pref
                      from    ownerdata
                      unpivot ( owner for pref in (owner1 as 1, owner2 as 2, owner3 as 3) )
                    ) u
                  inner join 
                    ( select  personid 
                      from    calendar
                      where   avail_state = 1 and the_date = (select dt from input_date)
                    ) c
                  on u.owner = c.personid
         ) j
         on o.taskid = j.taskid
group by o.taskid, o.owner1, o.owner2, o.owner3
;
```

**Output**:

```
ASSIGNED_OWNER THE_DATE     TASKID OWNER1 OWNER2 OWNER3
-------------- -------- ---------- ------ ------ ------
bob            3/2/2018      12345 john   bob    rick
```

Comment: This worked man! Whoa thank you so much. In the end I kept the WITH clause because I liked being able to keep the date as a variable. Thanks again!